# Traefik frontend redirects doesn't work

Tags: traefik

Hey i am trying catch all request to an Subdomain, with no matching rool and redirect them to https://localhost:8000 without subdomain and suburl. But there is no redirect, i just get the response from the backend.

```
[file]
  [frontends]
    [frontends.homeRedirect]
      entryPoints = ["https"]
      priority = 1
      backend = "homeRedirect"
      [frontends.homeRedirect.routes.everything]
        rule = "PathPrefix:/"
      [frontends.homeRedirect.headers]
        SSLRedirect = true
      [frontends.homeRedirect.redirect]
        regex = "(.*)"
        replacement = "https://localhost:8000"
  [backends]
      [backends.homeRedirect]
        [backends.homeRedirect.servers]
          [backends.homeRedirect.servers.server0]
            url = "http://frontend:80"
```

Is there something wrong with my file?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, a redirect on the entry point is more appropriate:

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    regex = "^http://subdomain.mydomain/(.*)"
    replacement = "http://myotherdomain/$1"
```

https://docs.traefik.io/v1.5/configuration/entrypoints/#rewriting-url

`localhost` inside the Traefik container is the container not the real machine.

Comment: thanks for the quick response.
what i want is:

https://(.*)localhost/(.*) => https:/localhost

but if there is a frontend for example Host:test.localhost then there should be no redirect for test.localhost